# Visual Studio publishing "extra" files with file publish

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-2.1

I use Visual Studio Folder Publish option to publish my Web apps to my IIS server. They are mostly ASP.NET Core 2.0 apps. Before I updated Visual Studio 2017 to the latest version my published web app would look like this in the IIS Site folder: (picture below)

[image: Screenshot 1]

Now that I have updated Visual Studio 2017 to the latest release of 2017, my Core 2.0 apps site folder has tons of files, like this:

[image]

I am not sure why, obviously nothing has changed with my app project files that I know of. I also noticed when I publish a newly created ASP.NET Core 2.1 web app, it only publishes the short list of files.

Does anyone know why this happens and if it is possible to fix (or even worth fixing). I haven't noticed any performance difference but my apps are not very performance intensive.

Comment: The 'es','fr','it',''ja','ko','ru','zh-Hans' an 'zh-Hant' folders are language resource folders, probably coming from a dependency of your project (e.g. a NuGet package). These won't affect performance, and they will only be used if you use those locales. You can remove them if you don't use those locales.

Comment: You say that *"nothing has changed wiht my app project files that I know of"*; but it's clear from the file lists that you have at least renamed the assembly, so maybe you have made other changes like updating the NuGet packages. I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: That is two different projects.  One I have made slight changes to and published since I upgraded Visual Studio.  The other one I have not.  I guarantee if I were to re-publish the one with the short list of files from the updated version of visual studio, it would all of a sudden have tons of extra files there.

Comment: I think it is something to do with an SDK that is built in to the latest version of Visual Studio 2017

Comment: I think you'll need to post your dependencies.